# Featured image details not appearing on main site

Tags: bug, status-completed

I'm not sure if this is intended, but in previous weeks it showed the title and the photographer beside the image. I liked that, but now it seems to be missing.

Answer (score 2):

I just updated the site message, you should see it now.

Comment: Thanks Jin! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The image details are still not visible.

Comment: Alse the link to the "next week" votation sometimes disappears.

Comment: There is a limit on the duration for these, which forces these to be renewed every 48 hours by hand. In addition, by adding an answer to a question flagged as [status-completed] *might* not get noticed by those monitoring issues.